# NAnt foreach loop folders recursive

Tags: loops, nant

Does anybody know how I could create a recursive loop with NAnt? I need to loop through all of my folders and upload the files to our webserver. I am using this NAnt ftp task (http://www.spinthemoose.com/~ftptask), however it doesn't seem to upload the entire directory. It uploads only the mentioned files in my put element.

Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Foreach task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/foreach.html). You can find examples looping through folders.

Full example:

```
<foreach item="Folder" property="foldername">
    <in>
        <items>
            <include name="YOUR_FOLDER\**" />
        </items>
    </in>
    <do>
        <foreach item="File" property="filename" in="${foldername}">
        <do>
            <echo message="${filename}" />
        </do>
        </foreach>              
    </do>
</foreach>
```

If you do not need folders, you can achieve your needs even with less code:

```
<foreach item="File" property="filename">
    <in>
        <items>
            <include name="YOUR_FOLDER\**" />
        </items>
    </in>
    <do>
        <echo message="${filename}" />
    </do>
</foreach>
```

Comment: I already checked that, but there is no example to do it recursively.

Comment: Example iv.Loops over all folders in the project directory. This is something you need.

Comment: That seems to work with the default folder from NAnt, however if I change it to: <foreach item="Folder" property="foldername" in="...." > then it doesn't show me the recursive folders. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you add "**" at the end of the path? This is key.

Comment: No, I did not. Sorry this is my first day using NAnt. Your example works now. What does ** do?

Comment: ** - Folders recursivelly :). Wait a minute I will update example with new version.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks a lot. Though it should be filename not filername (without the "r").

Comment: No, it better to be filename, but filername is ok too.

Comment: Just a quick followup question: How do I make it ignore my _svn folders?

Comment: Take a look on exclude element.

http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/types/fileset.html

Comment: Thanks Mike. I already did and it says that the _SVN folder is excluded automatically. Though it isnt'. I also tried to add the exlcude element, but that did not help either :(

Answer (score 3):

I believe this should give you the recursive list of folders

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<target name="task.recursive">
    <foreach item="Folder" in="${folder.current}" property="folder">
        <echo message="${folder}" />
        <property name="folder.current" value="${folder}" />
        <call target="task.recursive" />
    </foreach>
</target>

<target name="task.run">
    <echo message="${project.folder.root}" level="Info" />
    <property name="folder.current" value="${project.folder.root}" />
    <call target="task.recursive" />
</target>
```